# Save video to Torch tensor

Tags: python, algorithm, pytorch, ram

I have a long video (~20.000 frames) of resolution 480x854. I want to save this whole video to a `torch.tensor` (maybe `.pt` file). However, my RAM is not enough to load the whole video  at once. Is there a solution to do this? I don't really want to split it into multiple smaller files...

Edit: I just knew about video compression. Turns out video uses a much more efficienty way to store data, rather than naively stacking frames. So I guess storing the original video to tensor would not be possible, unless resolution and temporal downsampling are used.

Comment: So the video is a `mp4` file?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan yes. I intend to save it to a `pt` file, but not enough RAM

Comment: @K.XGai How about you try resizing the video to make it smaller ? Before loading it into pytorch ?

Comment: @AshwathS That will decrease the quality of the data, which is not what I aim for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the small memory of a video is due to efficient encoding algorithm :D
So it is just not possible to achieve that same size under a tensor format (which basically saves each image separately) without decreasing the quality of the original video.